# ASP.NET MVC How to choose between two dropdownlist to bind one property of my class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Here are my samples:

```
public class EntityBase 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Promotion : EntityBase
{    
    public int TypePromotion { get; set; } //0 = IdItem references Product, 1 = IdItem references Category
    public int IdItem { get; set; }
    //properties here
}

public class Product : EntityBase
{
   //properties here
}

public class Category : EntityBase
{
   //properties here
}
```

According the value of TypePromotion, I want to display ONLY the Products DropDownList or ONLY the Categories DropDownList (this is not a problem for me).

My view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TypePromotion)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TypePromotion, ViewBag.TypesOfPromotions as SelectList)
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdItem)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdItem, ViewBag.ProductList as SelectList)
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdItem)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdItem, ViewBag.CategoryList as SelectList)
</div>
```

In the POST Action, I only get the ProductID as IdItem property. How to "choose" between one and other in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For resolving this issue, you should not populate the Produc tList and Category List on loading. Just use a single dropdown list and bind the data through ajax call based on TypePromotion. So your html will be

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TypePromotion)
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TypePromotion, ViewBag.TypesOfPromotions as SelectList)
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdItem)
    <select is="IdItem" name="IdItem" >
    </select>      
</div>
```